# "The project does not know how to read the profile" in VS2022

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have a WinForms VB.NET application, which runs perfectly in VS2019. I need to create a menu bar (GUI editor not present in 2019).

When I run my application in VS2022, I get the error,

> "This project does not know how to run the profile <projectname>"

(where <projectname> is the name of my project)

I've tried:

1. Repairing VS2022
2. Installing .NET Development Tools
3. Creating a new profile

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I have fixed this problem by reinstalling VS2022.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Breaking API changes in Visual Studio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/breaking-api-list?view=vs-2022),  [Project migration and upgrade reference for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2022) and [Update a Visual Studio extension for Visual Studio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @user9938 Thanks for the links, but they aren't really of any help. I've not used any APIs as such, I've only used basic VB.NET commands. I'm not creating a VSIX Extension (its winforms), and as per the Project Migration and Upgrade "Visual Basic Windows Form: You can open the project in Visual Studio 2022, Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio 2017, and Visual Studio 2015."

Comment: Interesting, I just upgraded from 2019 to 2022 and simply opened my 2019 sln file in 2022 (my solution has many projects, including vb.net winforms, class libraries, console and c# winforms, class libraries, console, and webforms, all referencing multiple assemblies via class, nuget, and direct dll, and activex, etc. really) and I had zero issue. What is so special about your project?

Comment: When installing VS2022 I did need to select some items which are not selected by default, such as LINQ-To-SQL tools and Visual Studio Git, for some examples, but I always needed to do that when installing VS2019 on new machines as well. Maybe there is a tool your project also relied upon in VS2019, which you forgot about.

Comment: Do you use any NuGet packages in your project?

Comment: @djv - I did use the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project, it prompted me that it couldn't find the required plugin for the project, which I have installed after the prompt.

Comment: @user9938 No, I haven't used any NuGet Packages

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem

Comment: @user9938 I'll definitely report it to them
Also, it was a .NET 5 winforms, I'd forgotten to install the .NET 5 Runtime while installing VS2022,.I've installed it now, but it still doesn't work.